# Prestashop: Cannot add more than one object from JS array for GTM Data layer

Tags: javascript, arrays, smarty, google-tag-manager, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to populate array of dynamic variables for Data layer of Google Tag Manager but Smarty always shows me only the first object.

For example, I want to populate items of the completed order on the Order Confirmation page.
I add this to **OrderConfirmationController.php**:

```
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

         // this should work https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/554008-products-id-in-orderconfirmationtpl/
         $cart = new Cart($this->id_cart, $this->context->language->id);
         $products = $cart->getProducts();

         $prod_obj = array();

         foreach ($products as $product) {
             array_push($prod_obj, array('id_product' => '2'));
         }

         // $prod_obj = array(
         //     array('id_product' => ''),
         //     array('id_product' => 2)
         // );

         print_r($prod_obj);
         echo "<br>";
         print_r(array(
              array('id_product' => '1'),
              array('id_product' => '43')
         ));

         $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'is_guest' => $this->context->customer->is_guest,
            'prods' => $prod_obj,
            'HOOK_ORDER_CONFIRMATION' => $this->displayOrderConfirmation(),
            'HOOK_PAYMENT_RETURN' => $this->displayPaymentReturn()
        ));
```

When I echo them from the controller, I get the full array.

When I use it in **order-confirmation.tpl**, I always get only one of the objects. Somehow I cannot access all data of products of that order form $products array variable in **order-confirmation.tpl**.

I am using Prestahop 1.6.1.7.